# How to enter 'quit' to close progrom

Tags: c++, string, quit

I need help with closing the program by entering 'quit'

for example.

```
while(true)
{
  cout << "enter a name" << endl;
  std::getline (std::cin,input);
  if(input =='quit')
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

it is not breaking out or quiting, also how come you can't compare a string to a int?

i.e. : while (input != 'quit') <<-- that won't work also.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: `can't compare a string to a int`... Why can't you compare apples to oranges?  They are different things.  You can either attempt to *convert* your string to an int and compare or vice versa.

Comment: but I also need my input as a string because I will be comparing it with other variables later in the code.....is there a way to 'quit' program without converting to string?

Comment: I deleted my answer because you keep editing the question such that it completely changes the original question.  Please don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

`quit` needs to be in double quotes to be a `string`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "enter a name: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
        if (input == "quit")
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Broken" << std::endl;
}
```

[See it run](http://ideone.com/UwW1dL).

> also how come you can't compare a `string` to a `int`.

Because this behaviour isn't defined by the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) standard. Would `"1.0"` be equal to `1`?

Comment: Welcome to Version 3 of his question.  Hopefully it doesn't change again invalidating your answer :-)

Comment: @user2855990 Since you've got an answer to this question now, you should delete the older version of your question. Don't forget to accept this answer, too - click the check mark next to the answer to accept.